# Demanding processes lock up the entire system

Tags: linux, process, background-process

I write programs on a daily basis. However, whenever I try to do something a bit too demanding (e.g. multithreaded compilations) the system can lock up from too much CPU usage, I assume. Even when I'm doing nothing out of the ordinary at all, my language server can also hog the CPU so much that it freezes the entire system.

Can I prevent this from happening? If it happens, what can I do to get it unstuck? I usually have to power cycle my computer when this happens, thus losing some of my work in the process.

Comment: System lockups are unlikely to be because of the CPU being over-used, at least not directly.  Far more likely are: 1. inadequate cooling for your CPU, install a better heatsink & fan or water-cooling rig.  If your PC is a few years old, you may need to clean dust out of the CPU cooler.  2. not enough RAM. when you run out of RAM, the kernel starts randomly killing processes.  This isn't likely to cause the whole machine to lock up, though. Add RAM or swap space.

Comment: btw, re: cpu coolers and dust.  I've got an old FX-8150 machine which was prone to crashing when I did CPU-intensive tasks like compiling kernels or kernel modules like zfs, sometimes even on apt dist-upgrades.  Not every time, but often enough to notice the pattern.   I eventually cleaned the cooler with a small brush and a vacuum cleaner.  It's been fine ever since, not one crash.   It's also a lot quieter because the fan doesn't have to work anywhere near as hard to get rid of heat without all the damn dust clogging up the heatsink.

Comment: @cas my computer is always running at around 50-60 degrees C (which makes sense since it's a laptop) so I don't think inadequate cooling is the problem here? I also cleaned the fans a few months ago so I think it's even less likely that's the cause.

Comment: 50-60C should be fine.  and if you've cleaned up the fans recently, it probably doesn't need to be done again (unless you're in a very dusty environment or have furry pets).   I still can't help thinking that heat is probably the issue - multi-threaded compilations are **normal** use for a multi-threaded CPU and should NOT cause the machine to lock up.   Maybe try running something to monitor & log CPU temperatures over time, and see if there's any correlation between temp and crashes.   Ditto memory usage and process count.   Something like `munin` can do the monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Processes with a high CPU demand can be `nice`d or `reniced`d (the latter for already running processes). This has the effect that they give priority to other processes that want the CPU.

I don't think `nice` has an effect on disk IO or memory (ab)users. It is possible to limit this aspect of system usage but requires more complex tools, namely the cgroups framework.

Comment: Nice is very unlikely to help under these circumstances.